# Internal App Chooser

Tags: java, android

How to use default (dont want to create own) app chooser when selecting app for intent ... the chooser is shown, user choose one app and I call it explicitly with specific URI?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// Create and start the chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");
startActivity(chooser); //I dont want to start the intent ... just to know which one user chose
```

Comment: what is the problem? your code looks ok. You can add a type to your intent to filter for specific types of data. e,g,   intent.setType("plain/text");

Comment: I have to use "geo:" tag ... some apps dont understand the syntax that google implemented and needs specific format ... I need to know which one the user wants to run and then send apropriate uri

Answer (score 1):

> the chooser is shown, user choose one app and I call it explicitly with specific URI?

There is nothing built into Android that meets your requirements.

> I have to use "geo:" tag ... some apps dont understand the syntax that google implemented and needs specific format ... I need to know which one the user wants to run and then send apropriate uri

This is not possible, because the list of available apps for the user depends upon the `Uri`. You cannot even manually construct some "chooser" dialog that returns the choice rather than starts the activity, because you have no idea what entries to fill into the list.

If your objective is:

- Use a certain `Intent` if there are one or more activities that support it, or
- Use some other `Intent` if there are no activities supporting your first `Intent`

Then what you could do is:

- Craft your first `Intent`, and pass it to `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`. If this returns a non-empty `List`, you can call `startActivity()` on that `Intent`
- Repeat the above step for all candidate `Intent` structures, until you find one that you can call `startActivity()` on

Or, you can:

- Craft your first `Intent` and call `startActivity()` on it, wrapping that call in a `try`/`catch` block to watch for `ActivityNotFoundException`
- Repeat the above step until you successfully call `startActivity()` with no exception, or until you run out of `Intent` structures to try

There are more elaborate options as well (e.g., creating your own chooser using the results from *all* possible `Intent` structures rather than just one).